# Probabilities of Opening Certain Combinations in FE:Heroes

Tags: probability, statistics

Okay, so I'm playing a phone game called Fire Emblem Heroes. You have the option to unlock a set of 5 random heroes, one at a time. Some are more rare and powerful than others. A single unlock has this distribution:

3-star Hero: 58%
4-star Hero: 36%
5-star Hero: 6%

How do I go about calculating the most likely combination? My common sense is telling me that the most common combination is pulling zero 5-stars, two 4-stars, and three 3-stars. Also, how would I go about calculating a specific combination (like... getting two 5-star heroes and three 3-star heroes?)

Comment: Are there limited numbers of each, or is it possible to have five of the $3$-stars?

Comment: It's possible to have five of the 3-stars. There are a lot of them, and you can get the same 3-star hero multiple times